# button onclick issue with placeholders

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, events

I want to make like dynamic control generation and I managed to put my controls on placeholders .the problem I get when I tried to get info back from a control , since it won't "see" the controls in the handler .

i.e.
in test.aspx
 `<asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>`
`<asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder2" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>`

in code behind the page

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
TextBox txt = new TextBox();
Button btn = new Button();
btn.OnClientClick = "button_click";
//btn.Attributes.Add("onClick","button_click"); I tried this way , yet didn't work 
btn.Attributes.Add("runat","server");
PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(txt);
PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(btn);}
```

and the handler is :

```
protected void button_click(Object sender , EventArgs args){
string str = txt.Text; // I don't know if this would work , cuz this method didn't run onclick
 PlaceHolder2.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("intered :"+str));
}
```

thanks alot for each answer ,
as for accessing the control `TextBox tmp = (TextBox)PlaceHolder1.FindControl("input");`
where is "input" is textbox id I set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding the event in the wrong way.

It should be like, since you are adding a server side event:

```
btn.Click += new EventHandler(button_click);
```

Instead `btn.OnClientClick = "button_click";` this is the way we normally add a JavaScript function.

Comment: sorry to bother you , but what is the similar handler for dropdownlist ? should it be on the list or on each item ??

Comment: It should be like... DropDownList1.SelectedIndexChanged +=new EventHandler(DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged);

Answer (score 1):

`OnClientClick` refers to a JavaScript, which is used to execute a JavaScript function on the client side. If you want to use the `Click` event you assign it an event handler like this:

`btn.Click += myHandler;`

Where `myHandler` has the following method signature:

`protected void myHandler(object sender, EvetArgs e)`

Answer (score 1):

`btn.Click += new EventHandler(button_click);`

that's the code u are looking for

---

as for

`btn.OnClientClick = "button_click";
//btn.Attributes.Add("onClick","button_click")`

it's for client-side-scripting